# Dockerizing a stream app for SCDF

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have been able to set up spring cloud dataflow 1.2.0.RELEASE in a Kubernetes cluster, import the starter apps, and run simple flows such as "`http | log`".
But when I try to run my own Dockerized stream app in a stream like "`http | myApp | log`", I can't seem to get it to work... Deployment is fine, Kafka topics for the stream are created as expected, no error messages from any of the pods, but the myApp processor doesn't seem to be aware of the Kafka topics and therefore never receives data from the http source.

My question is this: is there anything special about dockerizing a streaming app for SCDF? How would the dataflow server configure a K8s pod to point it to the correct Kafka topics? I went to https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters and can't seem to find any Dockerfile examples, so I don't know how it's done for the starter apps.

My stream application is pretty straightforward; the code is like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class MyAppProcessor 
{
    ...

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
    List<MyPOJO> doProcessing(List<Double> doubles) {
        ....
    }
}
```

I also used `@ServiceActivator` but doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what dependencies you used for you processor.

I just [created a simple transformer processor and wrote up some notes on what I did](https://gist.github.com/trisberg/39eb9c6346cd3cd7d7c0616e152e141f#file-uppercase-notes-adoc).

See if that helps getting your example going.

The Data Flow server should set the properties that the stream apps need to connect to Kafka when they are deployed.

We really should create some more examples and document how to do the Docker build. We use the `io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin` when we generate the out-of-the-box apps, but I just used a simple `Dockerfile` in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the out of the box `http` and `log` apps for running the `http | log` flow? I assume that you imported the apps using the bit.ly links as specified [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_creating_and_running_streams_on_kubernetes) (you can also individually register the apps). How did you dockerize and made the image available to the SCDF server? The image needs to be available as a Docker resource and then register it.